# Determining the source of memory cache usage

Tags: 16.04, ram, cache

I'm troubleshooting a machine with slow downs due to heavy swap usage after running for several days. The system has 16 GB of ram and should generally be fine, save that a large volume of the ram is being used by cache and not being freed on need. Continual use will grind the system to a halt while as much as 12 GB are tied up in cache.

Before you mention it, I'm well aware of [Linux Ate My Ram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

A typical display of free after 3 - 4 days of running is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        4.4G        184M        280M         10G        116M
Swap:           15G        7.8G        8.1G
```

To troubleshoot, I've dropped swapiness to zero.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness 
0
```

Moreover, I'm unable to manually call a cache flush with any meaningful effect.

```
$ sudo su -c "free -h && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free -h"
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        4.4G        166M        280M         10G        104M
Swap:           15G        7.8G        8.1G
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        4.4G        186M        280M         10G        115M
Swap:           15G        7.8G        8.1G
```

I'm wondering if it may have to do with the on-board video with Skylake. Regardless, I'm unsure of how to continue to profile the issue, with most internet resources saying that cache usage is normal and will free as needed - when clearly it is not. Where should I look next?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find out about "memory cache" use `slabtop`, using `-s` you can sort the output and `c` is for the cache size, so use:

```
sudo slabtop -s c
```

For me most of the cache is related to `inode_cache`

---

And about "swap",
You can use `status`  file in each process directory in `/proc` to find out which one of them is using the swap.

For specific program:

```
cd /proc/$(pgrep -x programname)
grep -i swap status
```

To get a list of all process cache size:

```
cd /proc
find -maxdepth 2 -iname status -exec grep -i -e name -e swap {} \; -exec echo "---" \;
```

the output would be similar to:

```
---
Name:   atd
VmSwap:        0 kB
---
Name:   rsyslogd
VmSwap:        0 kB
---
Name:   cron
VmSwap:        0 kB
```

Comment: slabtop seems to have identified the culprit. I have ~12 GB tied up in a kernel space memory leak.

Another useful tool here to highlight the issue was `smem -tw`.

Comment: I was going to edit and mention `smem` too, good that you already know about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option may be checking the output of the following command to see whether there are huge size open files:

```
lsof -s | sort -nk7
```

Regarding cached memory not being freed:

- [Linux not freeing large disk cache when memory demand goes up](https://serverfault.com/questions/288319/linux-not-freeing-large-disk-cache-when-memory-demand-goes-up)
- [OOM despite available memory (cache)](https://serverfault.com/questions/515125/oom-despite-available-memory-cache/856010#856010)